# SQL if statement to select items form different tables

Tags: sql, select, google-bigquery

I am creating a new table joining 3 different tables. The problem is that I have some data that I want to select for `other_info` divided into two different tables. `table_1` has preference over `table_2`, but it is possible that in `table_1` are missing values. So, I want to select the value of `box` if it's not empty from `table_1` and select it from `table_2` if the value in `table_1` does not exist.

This is the code I have very simplified, but I think it's enough to see what I want to do. I've written an `IF ... ELSE` statement inside a with, and this is the error I get:

```
Syntax error: Expected "(" or keyword SELECT or keyword WITH but got keyword IF at [26:5]
```

Besides, I've tried different things inside the conditional of the if, but none of them is what I expect. Here is the code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE `new_table`
PARTITION BY
  Current_date
AS (
  WITH info AS (
    SELECT
      Date AS Day,
      Box,
    FROM
      `table_1`
  ),
  other_info AS (
    IF (...)
        BEGIN{
        SELECT
          Date AS Day,
          Box
        FROM
          `table_1`}
        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN{
        SELECT
          Date AS Day,
          Box
        FROM
          `table_2`}
        END
  )
  SELECT
    Date
    Box
    Box_description
  FROM
    `table_3`
    LEFT JOIN info(Day)
    LEFT JOIN other_info(Day)
)
```

Comment: For one, you're missing the closing parenthesis at the end. It closes your "create table as" statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not going to be able to embed an `IF` within a CTE or a Create-Table-As.

An alternative structure can be to union two queries with mutually exclusive `WHERE` clauses...  *(Such that only one of the two queries ever returns anything.)*

For example, if the code below, something is checked for being `NULL` or `NOT NULL`, and so only one of the two can ever return data.

```
WITH
  info AS
(
  SELECT
    Date AS Day,
    Box,
  FROM
    `table_1`
),
  other_info AS
(
  -=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-
  THIS BIT
  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  SELECT
    Date AS Day,
    Box
  FROM
    `table_1`
  WHERE
    (SELECT MAX(x) FROM y) IS NULL

  UNION ALL

  SELECT
    Date AS Day,
    Box
  FROM
    `table_2`
  WHERE
    (SELECT MAX(x) FROM y) IS NOT NULL
  -=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-
)
SELECT
  Date
  Box
  Box_description
FROM
  `table_3`
  LEFT JOIN info(Day)
  LEFT JOIN other_info(Day)
```

Comment: Perfect! I will do it like this

Answer (score 0):

In stead of the `if...`, you could do something like this (in MySQL):

```
SELECT *
FROM table1

UNION ALL

SELECT *
FROM table2 WHERE `date` NOT IN (SELECT `date` FROM table1)
```

I am not sure (as in: I did not test), but I do think this is also possible in google-bigquery

see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1a1e1047f9096cd8e229225b3894b643)